# Help create a block to insert view.phtml

Tags: blocks, product-view, custom-block, view

Help create a block to insert view.phtml. I have a layout file that outputs to buy in one click in the right column. I need to put this block alongside a buy button.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/oneclickorder.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="checkout.cart.methods">
        <block type="smasoft_oneclickorder/form" name="checkout.cart.methods.oneclickorder" template="smasoft/oneclickorder/form.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>

<!-- Show OneOrderClick form on product view page -->
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/oneclickorder.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="smasoft_oneclickorder/form" before="-" name="catalog.product.oneclickorder" template="smasoft/oneclickorder/form.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>

<smasoft_oneclickorder_index_success translate="label">
    <label>One Click Order Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="smasoft_oneclickorder/success" name="checkout.success" template="smasoft/oneclickorder/success.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.magento.success" as="magento_order_success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</smasoft_oneclickorder_index_success>

<oneclickorder_email_order_items>
    <block type="smasoft_oneclickorder/email_items" name="items" template="smasoft/oneclickorder/email/items.phtml">
        <block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</oneclickorder_email_order_items>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<block type="smasoft_oneclickorder/form" name="catalog.product.oneclickorder" template="smasoft/oneclickorder/form.phtml" as="oneclickorder" />`

Insert after `<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>` in the node `<catalog_product_view>`.

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml#L237

Then create a new node after

`<action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>`

Such as:

`<action method="append"><block>catalog.product.oneclickorder</block></action>`

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml#L258

Also be sure your Modules block exists you are referring to in the `type="smasoft_oneclickorder/form` as well as the phtml file referenced.

If you need to debug the XML structure:

`header("Content-Type: text/xml");
die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());`

This will output the entire XML tree that Magento compiles of every XML file it has gathered for the requests or has cached after generating.

Comment: It did not work, did everything you have written. Maybe possible just to insert a file view.html Bolok?

Comment: What does your Block `app/code/local/Smasoft/Oneclickorder/Blocks/Form.php` look like? Are you using a local layout file for your changes? Any errors in `var/log/exception.log` or `var/log/system.log` ?